# How this function call is ambiguous in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous, ambiguous-call, type-promotion

Consider following program: (See live demo here http://ideone.com/7VHdoU )

```
#include <iostream>
void fun(int*)=delete;
void fun(double)=delete;
void fun(char)=delete;
void fun(unsigned)=delete;
void fun(float)=delete;
void fun(long int);
int main()
{
    fun(3);
}
void fun(long int a)
{
    std::cout<<a<<'\n';
}
```

Compiler is giving following error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'fun(int)' is ambiguous
  fun(3);
       ^
```

But I don't understand why & how it is ambiguous? Does it involve any kind of automatic type promotion here? I know that calling fun with (3L) makes compilation successful.

Comment: It's ambiguous because none of the functions you have declared take a plain `int`, and the compiler cannot choose whether to convert to `double`, `char`, `unsigned int`, `float` or `long int`. `delete`d functions still participate in overload resolution.

Comment: @user657267 i think you can add it as an answer :)

Comment: @user657267: Better if you add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @user657267 is [right](http://ideone.com/twDa1L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably 3 can be interpreted as other types (like `char`, `unsigned`...), so it might be ambiguous for the compiler to know what function you want to call. You need to indicate value 3 is a `long int`.

```
#include <iostream>
void fun(int*)=delete;
void fun(double)=delete;
void fun(char)=delete;
void fun(unsigned)=delete;
void fun(float)=delete;
void fun(long int);
int main()
{
    fun((long int)3);
}
void fun(long int a)
{
    std::cout<<a<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: or call it like this: fun(3L)

Comment: I didn't read the comment of @user657267. My answer maybe not necessary here.

Comment: @PravasiMeet Yeah sure. As long as you make the compiler not confuse what to call.

Comment: avoid "C" style casting in C++. Prefer static_cast<long int>

Comment: @Krypton, that comment should have been an answer, in which case your answer wouldn't have been necessary. But they didn't, so your answer is relevant. However, why cast when you can simply make the type? I'm sure the compiler is smart enough to do the right thing, but it's much better practice to use the correct type in the first place.

Comment: @Nandu: personally I think C-style casts are better for simple scalar types - the C++ equivalent is more verbose and has no obvious advantages. YMMV of course.